# TypeDescriptor Peformance

Tags: c#, performance, typedescriptor

I've created a simple method to return a property I know is a string from a hierarchy of properties in an object.  Eg the object "contract" with the property "Person" with the Subproperty "Contact" and the subproperty (known already to be a string) "PhoneNumber"

I intend to use the method for a specific dynamic binding purpose.

Invoking the method would look like: GetProperty(contract, "Person.Contact.PhoneNumber");

I was wondering what the performance implications are of the following code:

```
 public string GetProperty(object obj, string name)
    {
        string[] index = name.Split('.');
        object result = null;


        for (int i = 0; i < index.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            result = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj).Find(index[i], true).GetValue(obj);

            if (result == null)
                return null;

            obj = result;
        }

        PropertyDescriptor pd = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(result).Find(index.Last(), true);

        return (string)pd.GetValue(result);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: And why not just obj.GetType().GetProperty(index[i], BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the names are known and fixed, a simple approach is:

```
dynamic obj = ...
string name = obj.Person.Contract.PhoneNumber;
```

The `dynamic` implementation is optimized internally, so this **won't** do massive amounts of reflection each time - it is resolved per-type only.

As for "how fast", you'd need to profile it - however, the regular reflection implementation is based on `PropertyInfo`, and is not *gloriously* fast. Fast enough for ad-hoc use, but in a tight loop, not so great.

If you want optimised and more flexibly than using `dynamic` (where you need the names at compile), then maybe [FastMember](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html); this has both type-based and instance-based APIs, and is deliberately optimized; usage for an arbitrary property fetch:

```
var acc = ObjectAccessor.Create(obj);
string propName = "PhoneNumber";
var value = acc[propName];
```

In that article, I also mention HyperDescriptor, a previous implementation that uses the `PropertyDescriptor` API (but optimized is) - however, unless you **need** the `PropertyDescriptor` implementation, I see no need to enforce using it.

Comment: The objects that are being accessed already exist, they're DataObjects.net entities, which I believe have a custom type descriptors? (http://dataobjects.net/)  The data is being grabbed to populate a custom CSV that the format is defined in a file at the time of population.  -- Does this make sense?

Comment: @Carl if it is using custom descriptors, then it is **impossible** for anyone to comment on performance; the performance is *entirely* determined by the custom implementation

Answer (score 1):

As always, test and see. I suggest a potentially better alternative.

1. Retrieve all properties once using reflection (or the methods of `TypeDescriptor`).
2. Create getters/setters using [dynamic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx) or [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).
3. Cache those getters/setters in a `Dictionary`.
4. Have your method look to the dictionary and invoke the getter/setter.

In my experience, this will always be faster (sometimes significantly) than anything which involves discovering information about a member at runtime. The string manipulation, looping, multiple method calls, etc. in your sample code looks far more expensive than using a key-based lookup and calling a single method.

The [documentation on TypeDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) states that caching is used internally for performance, so *how* much of a difference it makes can only be revealed with testing.